Cannot connect Spring boot with docker in wsl2
I have installed docker in wsl2 windows 11 and started it.
When in run my spring boot project i have an error :
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Password authentication failed for user 'user'
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Password authentication failed for user 'user']

my docker file
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=tennis_db'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234'
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=user'
    ports:
      - '5432'

  pgadmin:
    image: 'dpage/pgadmin4:latest'
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@gmail.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 1234
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 5050
    ports:
      - '5050:5050'

my application properties
spring.application.name=tennis
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tennis_db
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
server.port=8081

How can i fix connection failed to my database running in wsl2 ubuntu to my spring boot application runing to windows 11

Try to change your username from 'user' to 'user1'  for avoiding stack keywords

Looks like you haven't bound the postgres port to 5432
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=tennis_db'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234'
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=user'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  pgadmin:
    image: 'dpage/pgadmin4:latest'
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@gmail.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 1234
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 5050
    ports:
      - '5050:5050'


hi @Arun P Johny
Yes port 5432 I linked it to the postresql server and port 5050 I linked it to the pgadmin interface
